# share image from android app using action send with intent it's not work :(

Tags: android, facebook

i'm use

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("file//res/drawable/u.png");
 

sharingIntent.setType("image/png");


sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);


startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

//I use sumsung real for device.and i choose share on facebook.
//But content is empty  not my image to shared i can't shared image.

This is intent action send isn't use facebook sdk.
can you help me please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are going to wrong way to Access Drawable folder use this Way.

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package/drawable/fileName");
```

**You should try this way:**

```
      Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package/drawable/fileName");
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      intent.setType("image/png");

      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share"));
```

Comment: i have used your code but getting so many errors.....here is the Error list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347750/failed-to-send-image-file-using-shareintent-from-drawable-folder-in-android

Comment: Why cant one put `Uri` of image in `data` of intent rather than putting it as extra? I think it would make sense if uri is put in data and we set data and type for intent because type is for data.

Answer (score 2):

Try out this way:

> ```
>  Uri pngUri = Uri.parse("file//res/drawable/u.png");
>  Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
>  shareIntent.setType("image/png");
>  shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"YOUR TEXT HERE");
>  shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"YOUR TEXT HERE");
>  shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,pngUri);
>  PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
>  List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
> for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
>     if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) {
>         final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
>         final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
>                     activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
>                     activity.name);
>         shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
>         shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>                             | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
>         shareIntent.setComponent(name);
>         startActivity(shareIntent);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

It works fine for me . I am sure it will work for you also.

Comment: Text is not sharing as status .. with image