# Failed to Send Image File using ShareIntent from drawable folder in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, uri

I want to share image using intent ,i have used code from [answer of Dixit patel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291246/share-image-from-android-app-using-action-send-with-intent-its-not-work?rq=1).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/png");
        File.separator + "icon_ask_fatwa_one.png");
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+"drawable/icon_ask_fatwa_one");
        Log.i("imageUri",""+imageUri);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
}}
```

i am getting following error when trying to run this code in emulator:

> 01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-25
>   11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 01-25 11:50:57.697:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
>   01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
>   01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123) 01-25
>   11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
>   01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 01-25
>   11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126) 01-25 11:50:57.697:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997) 01-25
>   11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-25
>   11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491) 01-25 11:50:57.697:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>   01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599) 01-25
>   11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-25 11:50:57.697:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(265): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 01-25
>   11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at
>   com.android.mms.ui.UriImage.(UriImage.java:68) 01-25
>   11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at
>   com.android.mms.model.ImageModel.initModelFromUri(ImageModel.java:82)
>   01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   com.android.mms.model.ImageModel.(ImageModel.java:64) 01-25
>   11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at
>   com.android.mms.data.WorkingMessage.changeMedia(WorkingMessage.java:462)
>   01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   com.android.mms.data.WorkingMessage.setAttachment(WorkingMessage.java:363)
>   01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.addImage(ComposeMessageActivity.java:2747)
>   01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.addAttachment(ComposeMessageActivity.java:2883)
>   01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.handleSendIntent(ComposeMessageActivity.java:2812)
>   01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.initialize(ComposeMessageActivity.java:1776)
>   01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.onCreate(ComposeMessageActivity.java:1704)
>   01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
>   01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
>   01-25 11:50:57.697: E/AndroidRuntime(265):    ... 11 more

**Can someone pls correct code?**
**ADDED MANIFEST.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shareimage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.shareimage.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you added an intent filter in the Manifest? post your Manifest file

Comment: can someone help me i am still unable to share any image either from assets folder or from drawable folder i am getting mesage unable to open this attachment while sharing via bluetooth or gmail etc

Comment: same problem! Did you get any solution, plz share. :)

Answer (score 1):

use this code(i have edited your code):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/png");


        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.mm/drawable/ic_launcher");
        Log.i("imageUri",""+imageUri);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/> 
                <data android:mimeType="image/png"/> 
            </intent-filter>

Comment: i am testing on emulator now there is no error but no response as well

Comment: do you have the image icon_ask_fatwa_one.png in the drawable folder?

Comment: can i send apk ?can u please test on real device?

Comment: Sorry for the first answer i have tried this code and worked perfectly on my HTC Desire X,see the update

Comment: i am testing on device S2 android and nothing shows there is there any thing related to my device that i need to enable

Comment: No actually you need to remove the lines in the Manifest which i provided earlier

Comment: can u please come on chat i cant come becuaase of low reputation please come

Comment: @insomniac i have also same issue but i want to do with text and some image as well how can i do that

Comment: let me add you two to chat

Comment: well,i have uploaded the code into https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BztnhKc9Y8g6dVk0TTd3Q1A1Wjg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @insomniac  i am still failed to attach image on FB i have tested on device

Comment: i have put the path as assets instead of drawable

Comment: @insomniac can u please correct answer i am failed to share image so that i can accept your answer

Comment: can you wait till Monday,I don't have internet in my home,I'm on leave from job and I have a pretty "not good" internet connection in my phone,if you wait till Monday,I'll edit my answer or you could browse this link

Comment: www.nowherenearithaca.com/2012/03/too-easy-using-contentprovider-to-send.html?m=1